# Manage Images on appwrite - Flutter

Tags: flutter, appwrite

How can I maintain images based on its contents on AppWrite? its identical to firebase but it has no option to create folders or bucket from the app. So all images will be inside a single bucket. I will have access to file name and unique id
For example: I will have multiple products on my app and each product will have multiple images but the problem is all images will be stores inside the same folder. So How can I differentiate those images for each product?

Answer (score 0):

Buckets are more for managing what type of files and the size of each file that can be uploaded. For tagging files with additional metadata, I recommend maintaining a collection with that data. For example, in an app I created, I had a Photos collection with:

- created: ISO 8601 formatted timestamp
- file_id: $id of the file from the Storage API
- place_id: $id of place to link this comment to a Place
- user_id: $id of user to link this comment to a User
- text: description of photo

When a user opens a Place, I can fetch all Photos for that Place by listing the documents in the Photos collection filtering on place_id.

For more info on the design of my app, refer to [Building a Location-Based App with Appwrite](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-location-based-app-with-appwrite-48a2e2b6d4c2).